# "xz compression not available" after installing epel-release on centos7

Tags: centos7, xz, epel

As soon as I do a successful `yum install epel-release` (epel-release-7-6 or epel-release-7-8) on a fresh Centos7 installation then any subsequent `yum update` or `yum install` end with the error message `xz compression not available`. I tried reinstalling a few times and I get the same problem. This is all happening in a chroot but I don t think it s relevant.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing `pyliblzma` before `epel-release` solves the problem for me. Remove `epel-release` if it already installed.

```
yum remove -y epel-release
yum install -y pyliblzma
yum install -y epel-release
```

Comment: I did these and then tried 'sudo yum install cpp-ethereum'. I got the same error. Any suggestions?